# how to stop images auto resizing for posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image-size

I am trying to add quality images for my wordpress blog, I am adding
it but, in homepage and, list page images are coming very low size
like 320*240. which are very zooming images to 750*540 width. But in
single article page Image coming nicely. Please help me in this

this is the link [wethinkk.com](http://wethinkk.com)

Comment: Can you add some code to show us what you are trying?

Comment: I didn't added any code for it. Just simply added thumbnail function to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'

the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)

the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );  // Other resolutions
```

use your preferred one :)

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the code in your wordpress theme on Homepage and Loop page.
There is several ways to change the ratios of the picture in wordpress like aq_resize() function. Check your code in 3 pages, see what is happening, compare them and use the one that you want in all other places (ex. The code in single page is suitable so use that code in other pages.)